# Sum Union Query and get percentage for each row

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get the percentage of this query per row. So my query is this:

```
SELECT ITEM, AVG_VAL/sum(AVG_VAL) * 100 as PERCENT_TOTAL

FROM
(SELECT
'item 1' AS ITEM,
AVG(VAL) AS AVG_VAL

FROM TABLE1
WHERE DATE(t_stamp) BETWEEN '2016-06-02' AND '2016-06-02'

UNION ALL

SELECT
'item 2' AS ITEM,
AVG(VAL) AS AVG_VAL

FROM TABLE2
WHERE DATE(t_stamp) BETWEEN '2016-06-02' AND '2016-06-02') as t
```

The data for the first table (TABLE1) is

```
    ITEM    |   AVG_VAL
    item 1  |   45,042,179
```

The data for the second table (TABLE2) is

```
    ITEM    |   AVG_VAL
    item 2  |   30,428,453
```

I was hoping to get the output

```
ITEM    |   PERCENT_TOTAL
item 1  |       59.68
item 2  |       40.32
```

but when i try to group it by ITEM

```
SELECT ITEM, AVG_VAL/sum(AVG_VAL) * 100 as PERCENT_TOTAL

FROM
(SELECT
'item 1' AS ITEM,
AVG(VAL) AS AVG_VAL

FROM TABLE1
WHERE DATE(t_stamp) BETWEEN '2016-06-02' AND '2016-06-02'

UNION ALL

SELECT
'item 2' AS ITEM,
AVG(VAL) AS AVG_VAL

FROM TABLE2
WHERE DATE(t_stamp) BETWEEN '2016-06-02' AND '2016-06-02') as t
GROUP BY ITEM
```

I get

```
ITEM    |   PERCENT_TOTAL
item 1  |       100
item 2  |       100
```

I was also hoping I can show the total for the percent_total column, so that it will show

```
ITEM    |   PERCENT_TOTAL
item 1  |       59.68
item 2  |       40.32
Total   |       100
```

Comment: hocus, you ask a question then you scram, not answering a comment question 10 minutes later. Your data in your question is missing an item 2

Comment: @Strawberry I have two different tables TABLE1 and TABLE2. 'item 2' is from TABLE2.

Comment: @Strawberry i'm sorry for replying just now. i have no excuse for my late reply. i understand if you don't want to help. both item1 and item2 are total gallons, they are coming in from two different sites that is why we have two different tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way...

```
SELECT x.*
     , ROUND(avg_val/total * 100,2) pct
  FROM
     ( SELECT * FROM table1
        UNION
       SELECT * FROM table2
     ) x
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT SUM(avg_val) total
         FROM 
            ( SELECT * FROM table1
               UNION
              SELECT * FROM table2
            ) n
     ) y
```